# Worklight Application White screen appears after splash screen

Tags: android, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, phonegap-plugins, splash-screen

I am getting a White Screen after splash screen and then web page appears. I have configured the splash screen using cordova. Every time when app starts white screen appears for a while.

```
<feature name="SplashScreen">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen.SplashScreen" />
</feature>
```

preference like -

```
   <preference name="splashscreen" value="splash"/>
   <preference name="splashScreenDelay" value="10000"/>
```

Using above splash screen is not hiding after delay.

So I tried below way also

```
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000"/>

navigator.splashscreen.hide(); //call within device ready
```

Which hides the splash screen but getting white screen, not getting success. How can I resolve this issue.

Comment: I am having the same problem. Founf any solution yet?

Answer (score 2):

Changing the Cordova values will not help, as they are not used.

You are probably using either a slow device, or have creatung a very large app (in which case you should question what you are doing on application startup time that takes so much time).

If you are using Worklight 6.2 and above, you can control when will the splash screen be removed, and the app displayed.

Review the Splash Screen scection in the Common UI Controls tutorial: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/advanced-client-side-development/common-ui-controls/#splashscreen

To extend the duration of the default splash screen:

1. Uncomment the `autoHideSplash` option in the `initOptions.js` file.
2. When you're ready to hide the splash screen, use `WL.App.hideSplashScreen();`

Comment: You are not supposed to call to deviceready, this is done for you internally. You can add some delay in wlCommonInit and then call to hidSplashScreen.

Comment: Then see my text on if you're using a slow device or doing too much on startup.

Comment: Device is fast and on startup means on wlCommonInit u r saying?

Comment: on startup means whatever it is that you're doing - retrieving data from a slow network, or retrieving more data than you need, or do any action that will prevent that app from displaying until you're done with that action. Explain what your app is doing.

Comment: on startup only sqlite database initialization method get called nothing else.. rest is just web page call..

Comment: Consider doing it a bit further along and see if it helps.

Comment: still not working.. i tried to call that after initialization still getting same issue...

Comment: Well you're not being very forthcoming with your app, I I can't help. Provide something.